# Programmatically change Flex MenuBar item toggled property

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, mxml, menubar

I have this MenuBar control in Flex 3. How can I programmatically change the toggled property to `false`?

```
<mx:MenuBar labelField="@label" itemClick="itemClickHandler(event);" left="0" right="0" top="0" id="menuBar">
    <mx:XMLList>
        <menuitem label="File" data="top">
            <menuitem label="New" data="file-new"/>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem label="View" >
            <menuitem label="Grid" type="check" toggled="true" data="view-grid"/>
        </menuitem>   
    </mx:XMLList>
</mx:MenuBar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy enough, just need to bind the toggle property to a property within the class like so:

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable] private var _toggled:Boolean = true;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:MenuBar labelField="@label" itemClick="itemClickHandler(event);" left="0" right="0" top="0" id="menuBar">
        <mx:XMLList>
            <menuitem label="File" data="top">
                <menuitem label="New" data="file-new"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="View" >
                <menuitem label="Grid" type="check" toggled="{this._toggled}" data="view-grid"/>
            </menuitem>   
        </mx:XMLList>
    </mx:MenuBar>
```

Now when you change the _toggled property, it will reflect in the menubar.